# how to install pymedia for python 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python-2.7, ogg

```
Path for  OGG not found.
Path for  VORBIS not found.
Path for  FAAD not found.
Path for  MP3LAME not found.
Path for  VORBISENC not found.
Path for  ALSA not found.
Continue building pymedia ?
```

I am using python 2.7 on windows( 32-bit) and i got a source code from following link http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymedia/files/pymedia/
Can any one help me to solve my problem..

thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can find the unofficial copy of pymedia and several other packages for python 2.7 for windows:
[here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymedia)

I have used pymedia for python 2.7 on windows 7 from this source and it works great.

Comment: There is a more or less entirely complete library of python modules on this page (which I have used on occasion). However it is also worth noting that packages that are no longer maintained or for some other reason work on versions other than python 2.7 are included with binaries for 64 and 32 bit packages for multiple versions of python.

Answer (score 0):

When you start working with Python you will see that installing modules can be very frustating. So what i did was installing the "easy_install" https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools, then add it to your path and from now on to install a module you simply need to do this:

Open the command line-> type "easy_install name of themoduleyouwanttoinstal" (e.g: easy_install pywinauto) and voila

Comment: easy_install can get tricky if the module is not longer maintained. For instance, easy_install does not work with pymedia python 2.7